# Need Gradle build speed up (using 5 modules)

Tags: android, android-studio, module, android-gradle-plugin

I want to speed up Gradle build time in my project. Currently my project has 5 modules (developed by me) and no of modules will grow in future. I have read this [link](http://www.journaldev.com/12333/increase-gradle-build-speed). Second point says, **Try to minimize the use of modules.**

For my project, it is needed to use modules because of separation of project related code and reusable code. My project is taking so much time in Gradle compare to simple projects.

#### Done these things

**gradle.properties**
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms1000m -Xmx3000m
org.gradle.parallel=true

#### PC configuration

Intel Core i3-3210 @ 3.20 GHz 
8 GB RAM
64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Windows 8.1 pro, Android Studio 2.2.3 (64 bits), jdk1.8.0_101 (64 bits)

**studio.exe.vmoptions**
Changes in C:\Users\hgyanani.AndroidStudio2.2\studio.exe.vmoptions, will they change the scenario?
Currently these are the values:-
-Xms1500m
-Xmx3280m

Comment: http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/using-build-cache-in-android-studio-makes-gradle-build-faster/ and buy a faster computer (quad-core, SSD).

Comment: following might help - http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/build-cache

Comment: Then tell your boss to upgrade your PC.